# Resolving multiple "paths" in nested attributes

Tags: python, recursion

I need to resolve "multiple paths" specified like so:

```
p1 = 'item.element.[compact|fullsize].documents.[note|invoice]'
```

A list like this is expected:

```
['item.element.compact.documents.note', 'item.element.fullsize.documents.note',
 'item.element.compact.documents.invoice', 'item.element.fullsize.documents.invoice']
```

Code:

```
def resolve_paths(path):
    parts = path.split('.')
    depth = len(parts)
    new_paths = []
    for level, part in enumerate(parts):
        mult_branches = re.findall(r'\[(\w+)(?:\|(\w+))*\]', part)
        if mult_branches:
            mult_branches = flatten_iterable(mult_branches)
            for branch in mult_branches:
                interm_path = '.'.join(parts[:level] + [branch] + parts[level+1:])
                new_paths.extend(resolve_paths(interm_path))
            return new_paths
        elif level == depth - 1:
            new_paths.append(path)
    return new_paths
```

Several tests I wrote for this function pass, but I'm not entirely happy with this solution, it's somewhat convoluted. Better solutions? Simplifications?

Comment: What is `flatten_iterable()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These combinatorial problems typically have a compact and elegant solution using `itertools`. In this case, it is `itertools.product` you want to use:

```
from itertools import product

def resolve_paths(path):
    subpaths = path.split('.')
    for idx, subpath in enumerate(subpaths):
        if subpath[0] == '[' and subpath[-1] == ']':
            subpaths[idx] = subpath[1:-1].split('|')
        else:
            subpaths[idx] = [subpath]
    for path in product(*subpaths):
        yield '.'.join(path)
```

I have made it an iterator, which I like better for this type of problems.

```
>>> path = 'item.element.[compact|fullsize].documents.[note|invoice]'
>>> list(resolve_paths(path))
['item.element.compact.documents.note',
 'item.element.compact.documents.invoice',
 'item.element.fullsize.documents.note',
 'item.element.fullsize.documents.invoice']
```

Comment: I feel like this is the best solution presented so far.  It avoids recursion, is the most compact, and doesn't even use any regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

What do you think this will return for `part = '[compact|fullsize|x|y]'`

> ```
> re.findall(r'\[(\w+)(?:\|(\w+))*\]', part)
> ```

It will give:

> ```
> [('compact', 'y')]
> ```

Because, when a group matches multiple times, the last match overwrites previous matches, [as per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group).
If you want to support multiple patterns, I'm afraid you will have to do in two steps: matching and then splitting.

---

The part I don't like about this is that you split path to parts,
then when you need to recurse,
you re-join the parts again,
and in the recursion step it will be split again, and so on.
That's a lot of splitting and joining and iterations.
The recursive logic can be also tricky to understand.

Here's an alternative, without using recursion and unnecessary splitting, joining, iteration:

```
from collections import deque


def resolve_paths(path):
    parts = deque(path.split('.'))
    paths = [[]]

    while parts:
        part = parts.popleft()
        branches = re.findall(r'\[(\w+)(?:\|(\w+))*\]', part)
        if branches:
            orig_paths = paths[:]
            paths = []
            for branch in branches[0]:
                for path in orig_paths:
                    paths.append(path + [branch])
        else:
            for path in paths:
                path.append(part)

    return ['.'.join(path) for path in paths]
```

Answer (score 2):

The question's not too specific, so here's a "competing" solution to compare:

```
def resolve_paths(components, results = []):
  if not components:
    return results

  current = components[0]
  branches = split_branches(current) if has_branches(current) else [current]

  return resolve_paths(components[1:], list(append_all(branches, results)) or branches)

def append_component(acc, component):
  return acc + '.' + component

def split_branches(component):
  return component[1:-1].split('|')

def split_components(path):
  return path.split('.')

def has_branches(component):
  return component.startswith('[')

def append_all(branches, results):
  for branch in branches:
    for result in results:
      yield append_component(result, branch)


p1 = 'item.element.[compact|fullsize].documents.[note|invoice]'

print resolve_paths(split_components(p1))
```

## Positives

- `resolve_paths` is fairly simple and straight-forward. It's using an recursion and accumulator pattern which clears up a lot of bookkeeping.
- Overall the code's pretty explicit (I believe). For example segments like `split_branches(current) if has_branches(current) else [current]` are usually pretty nasty, arguably, however, the named helper methods enhance explicitness.
- I made a lot of assumptions about parsing that simplified out the regular expression. If these assumptions are wrong, that's okay, they're pretty easily changeable as they are in their own methods.

## Negatives

- Still recursive, so it could break in extreme edge-cases
- Some expressions are overloaded (e.g. `list(append_all(branches, results)) or branches`)
- The `list(list(append_all(branches, results)) or branches)`/`yield` pattern is kind of gross. I did it to alleviate the need for an accumulator list in `append_all`.